# Create a serializer for a list of serialized object using django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST and I have these three objects :

```
class Object1():
    name = ""

class Object2():
    value = 0

class Object3():
    list = [] # a list of object1 and object2
```

and I have their serializer like this :

```
class Object1Serializer(serializer.Serializer):
    name = serializer.CharField(max_length=30)

class Object2Serializer(serializer.Serializer):
    value = serializer.IntegerField()
```

How can I create a serializer for `Object3`

**Edit**

In my return response I want something like this :

```
{
    "Object1" : {
          "name": "name" 
    }
    "object2": {
           "value": 12
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Serializer Fields Documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields) — the basic idea would be to create a `Field` subclass that implements `to_native` to return the list you need.

There's the [drf_compound_fields](http://drf-compound-fields.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package that provides a `ListField` (and others) — this should either give you what you need or at least provide enough pointer to help you implement you own solution.

I hope that helps

Comment: I have read this but I don't that it's possible with that. See my updated question.